# Parallel linq on floyd warshall

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, graph, floyd-warshall

We were encountering this Graph problem and we needed to implement Floyd Warshall, 
So we did. Although we kinda disliked the algorithm because it is very slow.

We would like to know if it's possible to apply parallel linq on the second loop, so we can speed up the algorithm a little

> Question: Speed up the For loop with var `i`

```
private int[,] FloydWarshall(int[,] matrix)
   {
     var loopCount = matrix.GetLength(0);
     var next = CreatePredecessorMatrix(matrix);

        for (var k = 0; k < loopCount; k++)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < loopCount; j++)
                {
                    if (matrix[i, j] > matrix[i, k] + matrix[k, j])
                    {
                        matrix[i, j] = matrix[i, k] + matrix[k, j];
                        next[i, j] = next[k, j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return next;
   }
```

Comment: Try to write in your browser Floyd Warshall parallel implementation and click on a few of many links you will see. It will made your question obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very good suggestion by Viider Storm about a Parallel For

```
   private int[,] FloydWarshall(int[,] matrix)
    {
        var loopCount = matrix.GetLength(0);
        var next = CreatePredecessorMatrix(matrix);
        for (var k = 0; k < loopCount; k++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(k);

            Parallel.For(0, loopCount, i =>
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < loopCount; j++)
                {
                    if (matrix[i, j] > matrix[i, k] + matrix[k, j])
                    {
                        matrix[i, j] = matrix[i, k] + matrix[k, j];
                        next[i, j] = next[k, j];
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return next;
    }
```

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Does a [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx) in place of that "var i" for-loop not achieve the same speed up as the Parallel Linq?